# If - else Program

Tags: c, string, if-statement

Hi I have this code here trying ask the user about the location.When the user enters the location it just says bye.What is wrong in my code?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{

        char location[15];
        printf("1:Greencourt\n");
        printf("2:Corianthans\n");
        printf("3:Shop\n");
        printf("Enter a location\n");
        scanf("%s",location);
        if(location=="Greencourt")
        printf("Bisleri bottle cost 25 rupees\n");
        else
        if(location=="Shop")
        printf("Bisleri bottle cost 15 rupees\n");
        else
        if(location=="Corianthans")
        printf("Bisleri bottle cost 50\n");
        else
        printf("Bye");

        return 0;
}
```

Here is the output

```
1:Greencourt
2:Corianthans
3:Shop
Enter a location

Shop

Bye
```

Comment: Better use strcmp for compaiting strings

Comment: Since the question tagged with C++, I'd suggest you to use `std::string` instead of plain char arrays.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: @soon it's probably mistagged C++

Comment: @MichaelWalz Right, hint: headers.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, C++ allows you to use `stdio.h` as well.

Comment: @soon I'm no C++ expert in any way, but in that case, isn't it something like `<cstdio>`?

Comment: `==` is comparing the address of the pointer `location` and the string itself. Try it on a debugger and you'll see, the compiler even spills out warnings about this. You should use as other's have suggested, `strcmp()`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh, well, yes, `cstdio` *should* be used instead of `stdio.h`, but C++ also provides plain `stdio.h`.

Comment: Thank you very much guys strcmp() function worked properly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing strings (array of char) you can't use '==' operator.
You should use `strcmp` function:

```
int strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
```

so:

```
if(strcmp(location,"Greencourt") == 0)
```

Comment: it probably should be `if(!strcmp(location,"Greencourt"))`, since strcmp will return 0 if the strings are "equal"

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin yes, thanks

Comment: Take care that strcmp retuns 0 if strings are the same. Therefore the answer above is not completely correct but it goes to the right direction

Comment: Thanks strcmp() worked fine..

Comment: @Neeld you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you compare values with strcmp()

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
        char location[16];
 printf("1:GT\n");
 printf("2:Cori\n");
 printf("3:Shop\n");
 printf("Enter a location\n");
        scanf("%s",location);
        if (strcmp(location, "GT") == 0)
        printf("Bisleri bottle cost 25 rupees\n");
        else
        if (strcmp(location, "Shop") == 0)
 printf("Bisleri bottle cost 15 rupees\n");
        else
        if (strcmp(location, "Cori") == 0)
 printf("Bisleri bottle cost 50\n");
        else
        printf("Bye");

return 0;
}
 
~/MY_C $ ./a.out 
1:GT
2:Cori
3:Shop